# SwiftUI TVOS TabView remove blank area

Tags: swiftui, tvos

I have an apple tv app, I need to delete the blank area between tabView menu and my screen.

**My Screen:**

**[image: The screen that I hope:]**

**The screen that I hope**

**[image: The screen that I hope:]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) solved the issue

```
{
 ---- Content
 }
 .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```